# mysql client slow login strace

Tags: mysql, socket, mysql-cluster, strace

I am experiencing an issue with slow connections/logins to a loaded mysql server, even when connecting via the unix socket file (CentOS 6.3). Queries are completing very quickly -- `(0.00 sec)` in this case -- but the login takes up to several seconds, in this case:

```
real    0m3.128s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.011s
```

mysqld is running with `skip-name-resolve` and a `thread_cache_size` such that no new threads are being created during this issue. It is a **load-based problem**, i.e. logins are very fast when the server is idle. The server is handling about 60 connections and 300 queries per second on powerful hardware, so it is well underutilized.

Here is the section of an strace where it stalls, noted with the empty lines. I am assuming the stall on `read(` means it is waiting for a response from the server:

```
$ time strace mysql -e 'select 1'
[...]
read(3, "# /etc/services:\n# $Id: services"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "ervice\nfinger          79/tcp\nfi"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "     209/udp                    "..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "a-cluster      694/tcp          "..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "   1494/tcp                     "..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "603/udp                        #"..., 4096) = 4096
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f10609da000, 4096)            = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3318c32920}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY)             = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, 110) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\2003\341\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, "\2003\341\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [8], 4)   = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
read(3,



"e\0\0\0\n5.5.29-ndb-7.2.10-cluster-g"..., 16384) = 105
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99158576, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99158576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7f105216f000
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18312, ...}) = 0
brk(0x222b000)                          = 0x222b000
open("/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding=\"ut"..., 18312) = 18312
close(4)                                = 0
futex(0x986300, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
write(3, "P\0\0\1\205\242\17\0\0\0\0\1!\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 84) = 84
```

For what it's worth, this mysqld is an API node in front of NDB (MySQL Cluster), but I have a feeling it has nothing to with NDB, since queries against NDB tables are also returning very quickly.

**UPDATE**

configuring our php application to use persistent connections (`p:<hostname>` with mysqli) solved the problem completely, but I am still surprised at what a low connection rate this became an issue, compared to normal mysqld and Percona XtraDB Cluster.

to answer @HTTP500's question, we don't see `checking permissions` state, but do see a few of these at any given time:

```
395354 | unauthenticated user | connecting host    | NULL    | Connect | NULL | login                             | NULL             |
```

Comment: The stall is taking place right after the client connects and while it is waiting for the server to send its initial greeting. To diagnose this, I think you'll want to know what the server is busy doing during this interval instead of greeting the client. Since it's a load-based problem, my guess is that it's either busy with thread startup, or it's not accepting connections fast enough. Are there lots of clients frequently connecting and disconnecting or an insufficient client connection count limit?

Comment: about 60 connections per second are opened and closed, threads_created does not increase at all with the thread_cache_size in use.

Comment: If you do a SHOW PROCESSLIST while the client is connecting do you have some relatively long running thread in "checking permissions" state? How many users are in the mysql.user table?

Comment: @HTTP500, updated to answer your question. only a few users in the table.